# Lining up Char in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, formatting, char

Im having a problem lining up my letter grades with the scores from the students.  It prints out the scores with proper spacing, but when it gets to the if statement to assign a letter grade, it prints them like ABC instead of centered with the columns.  Any help would be appreciated.  The problem is in the calc_grades functions if statement.  I cant figure out how to get the grades to line up with the columns

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int numStus;
int numGrades;

void get_students(char stuNames[numStus][10]) //Get students names
{
  int i;
  int j;
    for (i=0; i<numStus; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the students name.");
        scanf("%6s", &stuNames[i]);
    }

}
void get_grades(int grades[numGrades][numStus], char stuNames[numStus]  [10])//enter each students grades
  {
  int x;
  int z;
    for (x=0; x < numGrades; x++)
    {
    for (z = 0; z < numStus; z++)
    {
      printf("Enter score for %s assignment %d:  ", stuNames[z],x);
      scanf("%d", &grades[x][z]);
    }
  }
}

void calc_grades(int grades[numGrades][numStus])
{
  int sum = 0;
  int sum2 = 0;
  int j;
  int k;
    for(j = 0; j < numStus; j++)
    {
    for(k = 0; k < numGrades; k++)
    {
      sum= sum + grades[k][j];
      sum2 = sum / numGrades;
    }
    if (sum2 >= 90)
    {
      printf("A   ");
    }
    if (sum2 < 90 && sum2 >= 80)
    {
      printf("B   ");
    }
    if (sum2 < 80 && sum2 >= 70)
    {
      printf("C   ");
    }
    if (sum2 < 70 && sum2 >= 60)
    {
      printf("D   ");
    }
    if (sum2 < 60)
    {
      printf("F   ");
    }
    sum = 0;
  }
}
void print_report(int grades[numGrades][numStus], char stuNames[numStus][10])
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
    for(i = 0; i < numStus; i++)
    {
      printf("%6s",stuNames[i]);

    }
  printf("\n");
  for(j = 0; j < numGrades; j++)
{
    for(k = 0; k < numStus; k++)
    {
      printf("%6i",grades[j][k] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}

int main()
{
  printf("How many students?");
  scanf("%d", &numStus);
  printf("How many assignments?");
  scanf("%d", &numGrades);

//Ask how many students

//Ask how many assignments

//Initializations...
  char stuNames[numStus][10];
  int grades[numGrades][numStus];
  char finalGrades[numStus];

//Get Student Names
  get_students(stuNames);
  get_grades(grades, stuNames);
  print_report(grades, stuNames);
  calc_grades(grades);
  int x;
  int z;


//Get Grades

//Calculate Final Grades

//Print Report

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code before posting it here.

Comment: Please don't try to use formatting markup in verbatim code; `**void` just looks (and is) wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are printing out the grade in the if statements. Looking at your print_report function, you have the formatting correct there, so why not keep it the same way?

What you have:

```
if (sum2 >= 90)
    {
    printf("A   ");
    }
```

What it should be:

```
if (sum2 >= 90)
    {
    printf("%6c", 'A');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you again heavyweight!  That did the trick.  Much appreciated